# How to change search icon hint to right in SearchView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, searchview

I have layout `search.xml` like this

```
<SearchView
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_8"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false" // <--- always expand
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:queryHint="@string/search"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
```

result :

[image]

I want to change search icon to right like picture bellow

[image]

How achieve like I want? Thanks.

Comment: You can use edittext instead in place of search view and set drawable right

Answer (score 4):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
   android:id="@+id/searchView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
   android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think about this but it's more like a hack-ish which is changing the following in your java class:

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

Then, go ahead and set a search icon image on the right/end of your toolbar then set that search icon to visible once user clicks on the search icon:

```
searchIconImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```